# LLVM def-use for alloca values

Tags: llvm, alloca

I  have been exploring def-use for alloca values.

I have the following piece of IR code -

```
continuation:                                     ; No predecessors!
  %iftmp = phi i32 [ 8, %then ], [ 20, %else ]
  store i32 %iftmp, i32* %datasize
  %res = alloca i8
  store i8 -113, i8* %res
  store i8 -127, i8* %res
  %res3 = load i8, i8* %res
  ret i8 %res3
```

On running the def-use chain for "%res" , and printing the instruction that is using "%res" . Following was the output -

```
for val=
  %res = alloca i8

instruction with usage=
  %res3 = load i8, i8* %res

instruction with usage=
  store i8 -127, i8* %res

instruction with usage=
  store i8 -113, i8* %res
```

I find that the loads are seen before store. Is there any way to get the "use"s of the alloca value in exactly the **same order** of instructions as they appear in the IR ?